# Ocaml: This expression has type 'a list * 'a list -> bool but an expression was expected of type bool

Tags: ocaml

I just started learning Ocaml and am playing around with recursive functions. Ocaml Compiler is telling me that recursively calling helper in "if h1=h2 then helper t1 t2" causes an error: This expression has type 'a list * 'a list -> bool but an expression was expected of type bool. I understand that it is telling me that the compiler is expecting a boolean but instead gets a function that returns the boolean. But I have no idea how I can fix this. Any help is appreciated

```
let rec a_func l =
  let rec helper tmp l1 = function
      | [], [] -> true
      | _, [] -> false
      | h1::t1, h2::t2 -> if h1=h2 then helper t1 t2 else helper [h2]@l1 t2
  in helper [] l
```

Answer (score 4):

Your definition `let rec helper tmp l1 = function ...` defines a function `helper` which takes *three* arguments: `tmp`, `l1`, *and* an anonymous argument which is used in the pattern match. This is because the `function` keyword introduces an additional argument, it does *not* mean a pattern mantch on previous arguments.

It looks like you want to match on `tmp` and `l1`. In that case, you can write `let rec helper tmp l1 = match tmp, l1 with ...`. You can also write `let rec helper = function ...`, but that defines a function that takes a *pair*, so you would have to call it as `helper (t1, t2)`, `helper ([], l)` etc.

You will also need to put parentheses around `[h2]@l1`. Note that a more idiomatic way of writing this is `h2::l1`, but you will still need the parentheses. Finally, OCaml will warn you that you have no case for the pattern `([], _::_)`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!