# How to pass value of recursive function instead of definition

Tags: ocaml

I have this very simple recursive function, to add a branch to a tree from a list of char.

```
type tree = Node of bool ref * (char * tree) list ref

let rec create_branch lc = function
    [] -> Node(ref true, ref[])
    | x :: l -> Node(ref false, ref [(x, (create_branch l))])
```

I would expect this to create a tree containing only one branch, which would have a bunch of "false" nodes with char transitions until the final node which would be true.

But I'm getting an error:

Error: This expression has type (char * (char list -> tree)) list ref
       but an expression was expected of type (char * tree) list ref
       Type char list -> tree is not compatible with type tree

I think I understand that this means that my recursive call seems to, for some reason, get passed as a reference to the actual function (hence the (char list -> tree)), instead of its return value, which would simply be a tree.

I'd like to know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `function` keyword creates a lambda expression, in which you can do multiple clauses of pattern matching.

The function you wrote takes two parameters, `lc` and the one being pattern matched.

You can replace `function` with `match lc with`, or delete `lc` to fix it.

This is the same problem with
[Ocaml: This expression has type 'a list * 'a list -> bool but an expression was expected of type bool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42201312/ocaml-this-expression-has-type-a-list-a-list-bool-but-an-expression-was), but I know it can be difficult to search for errors like that.

Comment: It worked, or at least it fixed my type problem. To make the actual code work will probably still be a ton of work, but you helped a lot. Thank you. OCaml is pretty weird.